# Get mounted disk space on Temp in Linux machine

Tags: linux, perl, diskspace

I am new to perl world. I written one perl script for calculating free disk space. But whenever output generates, it gives me different number than what actually shows using df -h command.

So my requirement is i want to show specific mounted free disk space. E.g I want to show only /boot "Use%" figure and it should match with df -h command figure.

Please find my script for reference as follows by clicking link named Actual Script.

[Actual Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOCwV.jpg)

Comment: Please don't link to images of code. It is much better to paste your actual code into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `df` function from [`Filesys::Df`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::Df)
module returns a reference to a hash ([`perldoc perlreftut`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)) with `fs` info fields

#### Example:

```
$VAR1 = {
    user_bavail => '170614.21875',
    user_blocks => '179796.8203125',
    user_fused  => 408762,
    used        => '9182.6015625',
    fused       => 408762,
    bavail      => '170614.21875',
    user_used   => '9182.6015625',
    su_bavail   => '180077.20703125',
    ffree       => 11863876,
    fper        => 3,
    user_favail => 11863876,
    favail      => 11863876,
    user_files  => 12272638,
    blocks      => '189259.80859375',
    su_favail   => 11863876,
    files       => 12272638,
    per         => 5,
    su_blocks   => '189259.80859375',
    bfree       => '180077.20703125',
    su_files    => 12272638
};
```

So you free space is

```
my $ref = df($dir, 1);
print $ref->{bavail} . " bytes\n";
```